# Get image pixels using graphicsmagick

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

Currently I'm using `pngjs`, like described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14276341/1420197), but I want to see how to get the pixels of an image using GraphicsMagick.

I'm using [`gm`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm) as wrapper for GraphicsMagick. I couldn't find any information how to get the image pixels.

I would like to have something like:

```
myImg.getPixel(x, y, function (err, pixel) {
   // pixel: { r: ..., g: ..., b: ..., a: ... }
});
```

I'm wondering if `toBuffer` would help:

```
gm('img.jpg')
  .resize(100, 100)
  .toBuffer('PNG',function (err, buffer) {
    if (err) return handle(err);
    console.log('done!');
  })
```

Having the buffer, maybe I'm able to calculate somehow the pixel colors...

What is the easiest way to get the pixel info (r, g, b, a) at given coordinates (x, y) using graphicsmagick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [pngjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pngjs) library you can parse the PNG buffer obtained from GraphicsMagick:

```
const PNG = require("pngjs").PNG
    , gm = require("gm")
    ;

let img = gm("path/to/image.png");

// Get the PNG buffer
img.toBuffer("PNG", (err, buff) => {
    if (err) { ... }

    // Get the image size
    img.size((err, size) => {
      if (err) { ... }

      // Parse the PNG buffer
      let str = new PNG();
      str.end(buff);

      // After it's parsed...
      str.on("parsed", buffer => {
        // Get some pixel from the image
        let x = 27
          , y = 9
          ;

        let idx = (size.width * y + x) << 2
          , rgb = {
              r: buffer[idx]
            , g: buffer[idx + 1]
            , b: buffer[idx + 2]
            }
          ;
      });
      str.on("error", ...);
    });
});
```